# How to make 'selectable' custom html text in FullCalendar day cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add some custom html into the FullCalendar day cell.

It won't let me highlight the text (so that it would be possible to copy the text), as I *think* that some sort of overlay is stopping me, I've attempted to override this with a z-index but it still isn't working.

I've added the following into the FullCalendar settings, and although this displays 'Test' in each day cell, I can't figure out how to enable the simple text highlighting I need in order to copy and paste as described above.

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.append("<div><p style='color:black;'>Test</p</div>");
}
```

Comment: I don’t think that is an overlay issue, but rather has to do with the drag&drop functionality (at least in demos such as http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/basic-views.html; if your situation is different, then please describe it.) Drag&drop and copy&paste don’t work well together, for obvious reasons. So if you want to be able to copy event descriptions, then your best bet is probably to disable the drag&drop functionality somehow.

Comment: I think you're correct, what i'd like to do is disable drag and drops as the information within each day cell is going to be static (loaded from a db, populated into the calendar as a readonly display of information).